# propel not recognizing array

Tags: php, propel

I have a custom function in one of my query classes (simplified):

```
public function applyStandardFilters($currentState) {
    return $this->useIdbAdsQuery()
                     ->filterByCurrentState($currentState)
                 ->endUse();
}
```

when I pass it an array

```
currentState: Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 5
)
```

the following SQL is generated:

```
AND idb_ads.current_state=1
```

instead of

```
AND idb_ads.current_state IN (4,5)
```

how can I fix this?

EDIT: version 1.7

Comment: Somebody still using Propel :P  Seriously, you should say a version.

Comment: @renoirb - can I ask whats wrong with Propel? Its works very well, it is well supported by frameworks such as symfony and is well documented. Just curious

Comment: I always used symfony 1.x and Symfony2 with Doctrine, I prefer Doctrine2 Repository pattern (instead of Active Record), the thing I love from repository is that it is easy to make transactions boundary, managing plain object "entities", and how Doctrine2 caches already fetched results. That being said, I don't know if Propel2 changed much, I thought Propel was dead, but besides of that sure it works! Always better than handwriting queries. Just need to understand ins and outs of the ORM and not trust in magic :)

Comment: sorry to use this post to have a discussion on ORM's.  Ive had a play with both Doctrine2 and Propel 1.6 and found Propel much easier to achieve what I wanted.  I was just curious.  Thanks for responding =)

Answer (score 0):

I found the error in the end. The column type in the DB was `tinyint(1)` which does not exist and is just a one-byte integer (see [the relevant mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html).

Propel reverse-engineered this to a boolean, instead of an integer. Changing that and regenerating the base classes solved the problem.